# Can one use optical slave in a triflash bracket setup?

Tags: off-camera-flash, lighting-modifiers

So there are these modifiers that you could use a triflash bracket and use it to build a large modifier.

Typically one would need radio triggers for each of those.

I'm wondering if it's possible to just have one on a radio trigger, the others on optical slave? Being inside the modifier, it should have no problem sensing the initial impulse from the one on the radio trigger.

Though I kind of have my doubts - the light output might be more like 1 speed light  and then two speed light...

Answer (score 1):

This is very dependent on the delay accumulated by both the radio and optical triggers, also on the shutter speed you are using. Usually, as long as everything triggers at all, problems can be remediated by going a shutter speed or two lower than maximum sync speed.

Be aware that some (especially cheapish) radio trigger receivers can behave erratic (eg only firing sometimes or having very incalculable delays) when too near the transmitter, or too near each other, or galvanically sharing a ground (metal bracket!) with each other and/or the transmitter, or having a big metal piece connected to their hotshoe ground at all (or even close by).....